# Why do canned sardines have no protein scum?

Tags: canning, sardines

I believe canned sardines are cooked in the can.  I notice they never have any protein scum, albumin etc.  Do you know why or where in the cooking process is it removed?

Comment: I've never seen the term protein scum used. Googling turns up aquarium cleaning stuff. Are there "protein scums" other than albumin?

Comment: By "protein scum" are you talking about the gray scum that forms when boiling, for example, chicken?

Comment: @JohnFeltz yes.

Comment: @Caleb i'm not sure if it's albumin but it may be.

Comment: @Caleb "albumin" would be a very weird way to refer to the protein scum created by cooking meat. First, it is composed of a ton of other proteins than simple albumin. Second, albumin can be found in multiple states in food, so simply referring to "albumin" when one means the scum would be too imprecise. "Scum" is a precise term, and in boiling meat, it is indeed composed of different proteins.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to answer concisely, because there are many variations in processing before the Sardine hits the canning retort (a sterilization pressure cooker). Recall that there are sardines "in oil" "in spring water," even in "hot sauce." Here is a [video example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SKD8eGpkKx0).

Sardines are canned under both *pressure* and *temperature* in the canning retort. I believe the *pressure* factor has more impact in supressing what you call *scum* ** though temp prolly plays a factor as well.

Home brew example: I rarely find scum like formations in my pressure cooker. I do find congealed fat on cool down.. but congealed protein.. not so much.

** Not sure if the scum you are thinking of is congealed fat, or protein.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the lack of oxygen in the tin when cooked - I believe.

Comment: You're answer could be improved by expanding to include more detail, like discussing why the presence of oxygen allows protein scum to form.